# How to get the field collection field value in twig file?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I have field collection field. I need the field value in field in twig file.

How to print the field value.

Image of the below code.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ kint(item.content) }}
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Need the "field_project_from" date field value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say you have a field collection `field_test` and the field collection has fields say `field_name` and `field_age`, you can access them using the below snippet.

```
{% for details in node.field_test %}
    Name: {{ details.getFieldCollectionItem().field_name.value }}
    Age: {{ details.getFieldCollectionItem().field_age.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

See [reference](https://www.drupal.org/node/2798073) and 
[another reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192064/extracting-the-values-of-field-collection)

I assume `getFieldCollectionItem().field_name.value` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good answer to the question, how to get the field collection field values, from @AkiShankar. But you only get the values as they are stored in the database and you have to format the content yourself.

If you want to print the formatted fields use the template of the field collection item.

The theming for field collection items is the same as for nodes. Both are entities. And only if have a template of the entity or of a field inside of the entity you are able to handle the rendering of the field output.

Answer (score 1):

@AkiShankar's answer works, but creates a lot of work for the developer in the twig template.  If you work directly off of the entity and do getFieldCollectionItem(), you are forced to validate the data within your twig, and you can't use field formatters, so for something like a google map, pulling the data directly out without a formatter doesn't work so well.  If you want to be able to use view modes in your field collection (this works for paragraphs and entity references as well), you can create a custom field formatter for your entity that renders the fields.  You can then access the child fields easily in the parent twig:

At /modules/custom/mymodule/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/EntityComponentFormatter.php

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\EntityReferenceEntityFormatter;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'entity reference rendered entity' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "entity_component_formatter",
 *   label = @Translation("Rendered entity variables (available to parent template)"),
 *   description = @Translation("Entity with fields available in parent template."),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "entity_reference"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class EntityComponentFormatter extends EntityReferenceEntityFormatter {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $elements = parent::viewElements($items, $langcode);

    foreach ($this->getEntitiesToView($items, $langcode) as $delta => $entity) {
      $view_builder = $this->entityTypeManager->getViewBuilder($entity->getEntityTypeId());
      $elements[$delta] = $view_builder->build($elements[$delta]);
    }

    return $elements;
  }

}
```

You can iterate through in your twig like this:

```
{% for key, item in content.field_my_field_collection %}
  {{ item.field_1 }} 
  {{ item.field_2 }}         
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't want to create a custom formatter, you can do the same thing in hook_entity_view:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view().
 *
 * Gets the output for extra fields.
 */
function mymodule_entity_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {

  if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'node' && $entity->bundle() == 'article' && $view_mode == 'myviewmode' && !empty($build['field_my_field_collection'])) {
    $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('field_collection_item');

    $build['field_my_field_collection'] = $view_builder->build($build['field_my_field_collection']);
  }

}
```